# Send value by codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I send value by pagination link in codeigniter?
If a category value equl 3  when I press any pagination link send 3 to the goal page.

for example like this :
`$cate=3;`

```
<a href ="goalpage.php?cate=$cate> linktext </a>
```

Comment: what is _"codeignaiter"_ ?

Comment: this explains how: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Configure `Codeigniter` `pagination's` setting like below:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$this->pagination->page_query_string = FALSE;
$this->pagination->query_string_segment = 'cate';
......
$this->pagination->create_links(...parameters of yours...);
```

After you set these two preferences the  logic in `Pagination` class method `create_link` will get cate from `$_GET` and set it as `Pagination::cur_page` value and make the correct link to your goal page.

I just describe how to make `Codeigniter's Pagination lib` receive current page from your `http query string`, and the other work are associated to your program's specific occasion.